# handing over a promise

Tags: c++, concurrency, c++14

The connected pair of a promise and the future created from it constitute a concurrency-safe one-time communication channel. So far so good. However, there is one detail where I could not find a definitive answer: What about passing the promise itself?

Obviously, the standard usage pattern is to create the promise, get the future from it, and then create a new thread, passing the promise as argument. Since the new thread is created after the promise (and by the guarantees of the thread framework itself), the thread function sees all its arguments completely initialised once it starts executing.

*But the question is...* -- what if I want to pass a new promise to another thread already running at that point? As motivation, passing that promise could be part of a "work task", which we just expect for some reason to be completed within that other thread (Please note that I do not want to engage into the discussion if doing so is good design).

Based on my general understanding of concurrency concepts, I draw the conclusion that we **must guard that hand-over with some other means of synchronisation**. E.g. locking a Mutex. Or passing it via an atomic pointer variable, or setting an atomic flag afterwards for signalling (with memory_order_acq_rel).

**Question**: is that conclusion correct?

Or is that additional synchronisation/guarding unnecessary?

Is there some "magic" within promise, so that I could just move it into some target variable in that other thread? (I would assume no, there is no such magic)

Comment: In general if documentation doesn't state an object (code) is threadsafe then it isn't. And thus you need to guard it with a mutex (atomic pointers do not protect the object only the pointer itself). In this case https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/promise : Concurrent access to the same shared state may conflict.

Comment: regarding Atomics: correct, however, when using the right memory-order, you also get the guarantee that if you see the change on the pointer, all changes to the pointee that "happened-before" in the sending thread will also be visible from the very moment the receiving thread sees the change to the pointer